# formatting JSON long string with newline on VSCode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a JSON file.

```json
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "author": "Me",
  "customJSON": "{\n\"something1\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something2\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something3\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something4\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something5\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something6\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something7\": \"leftEye\",\n\"something8\": \"leftEye\"\n}"
}
```

As you see, `customJSON` value is string and it has very long length so vertical scroll activate.

Even though VSCode provides default JSON formatting but it doesn't format long string like `customJSON`.

If there are any extensions for my needs please suggest me :)

**What I want to see on VSCode**

```json
{
  "title": "My Title",
  "author": "Me",
  "customJSON": "{
    \"something1\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something2\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something3\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something4\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something5\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something6\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something7\": \"leftEye\",
    \"something8\": \"leftEye\"
  }"
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there is an extension that will do this.  You could do a find/replace to do it when you want but you would have to do it each time.  Let me know if you want to see it.

Comment: is the result valid JSON?